# SQL Server 2008 R2 Merge Replication Change Identity management on an article

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge-replication

I have inherited a merge replication publication nightmare. There is an article that is being published but it does not have an Identity Range being set for either the publisher or subscriber yet is set to manual Identity management. I would like to change it so that it can do even numbers on the publisher and odd numbers on the subscriber without having to create a new publication.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what your data and tables look like and an example of what you have tried and what you would like to achieve.

Comment: I have come to conclusion there is not a quick behind the scenes fix for this.  To alleviate the current issue, I have simply deleted the article and added it back with Identity management set to auto.  

To change the Identity seed it looks like I will have to create a copy of the old table with the new identity settings, import the old data into the new table, delete the old table, rename the new table, and reattach all the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To alleviate the current issue, I have simply deleted the article and added it back with Identity management set to auto.